# Programmatically close all open cdk-overlay

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, focus, overlay

I have a MatTabGroup with multiple MatTab. I set a keyboard shortcut to change the active tab (ctrl+-> = next tab and ctrl+<- = previous tab). I also set function that focus the first input of a tab after activation.

The problem is: when the first input is, for instance, a mat-autocomplete, the focus shows the autocomplete overlay (which is perfectly fine) and, when I use the shortcut the change the tab, even with the new input focus on the new tab, the mat-autocomplete of the previous tab doesn't seem to fire the blur event and, thus, the overlay stays open until I tab out or click.

I've tried to manualy remove the "cdk-overlay-container" but in this case the autocomplete of this element can't be shown again.
I've also tried to call the "blur" function on the mat-autocomplete's input element but it doesn't work.